# Transfer learning scenario

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, transfer-learning

I have an interesting question and I need some help. Consider the following problem. Let's suppose that I am doing regression with neural networks. As input I have a set of measurements, arrays of $N$ values, that are nothing else as $f(x_i)$ with $i=1,...,N$. The network should spit out one parameter that model $f()$. For example if you consider
$$
f(x)=\frac{A^2}{x^2+A^2}
$$
the network should, given the $f(x_i)$ return an estimate of $A$. Now that is easy. I did it and it worked beatifully. Now to my question. Let's suppose that I want to use the trained network I have for new data, and in particular for data that is generated by the function
$$
g(x)=f(x)+C
$$
where $C$ is a constant. I don't want to train the network again, since it should have learned already how to extract the parameter. Is there any smart way of, let's say, using the pre-trained network and simply get the same results? I am thinking something on the following lines:

1. I train my network with data generated from $f()$
2. I would like to give my model let's say just a few observations generated with $g()$ (not thousands, but just < 10)
3. The model should be able to adapt and give now the right results for $A$

Any idea? Would really appreciate any hint...

Comment: You've left comments on both your answers which suggest that you have a different question in mind. Please edit your question to reflect what problem you face and what you would like to know.

Answer (score 3):

In this particular case you can take the trained network and prepend an extra layer that adds a constant to all inputs. Now you can train on the data generated from $g$, *keeping all the old weights fixed*, only learning this one constant. This should be straightforward even with a few samples since it is only one parameter.

This extra prepended layer will convert your inputs $$g(x_i) = f(x_i) + C$$ to $$g(x_i) + C_\mathrm{learned} = f(x_i) + C + C_\mathrm{learned}$$ and $C_\mathrm{learned}$ should converge to $-C$.

Comment: Thanks. You can also check my comments I made on the next answer. But your idea is actually very interesting. So I could add a layer and just train with the few new observations to kind of compensating for the change... I have to see if it works. I have already data I can try your idea on...I guess it could work since the pre-trained network is already closed to a good minimum of the cost function... By the way my real-life problem is more complicated. I don't know if the change is just a constant...

Answer (score 1):

I assume the constant $C$ is unknown, otherwise the solution is trivial. I don't see the need to train another network at all: just estimate $C$ from data. You have two datasets:

$$D_1=\{f(x_i)\}_{i=1}^N, \quad D_2=\{g(x_j)\}_{j=1}^n $$

Again, I assume $\{x_j\}_{j=1}^n$ is not a subset of $\{x_i\}_{i=1}^N$, otherwise the solution is again trivial. Anyway, as long as the $x_i$ and $x_j$ are both iid samples from the same distribution, $f_i$ and $g_j$ are iid samples of random variables whose means differ by $C$ (linearity of expectation). Thus estimate $C$ as

$$\hat{C}=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^N f_i}{N}-\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n g_i}{n}$$

0 training time!

Comment: Thanks. Actually that was just an example. My real-life scenario is a lot more complicated. The data are coming from a sensor that measure a dephasing of laser light. The material tends to get older and less reliable so the measurements tend to degrade slightly. So I don't have the functional form or I don't know how things are changing. I just know that the physical effect driving the measurements is not changing. I know this makes everything not easier...